# Sending a GET request in JavaScript from Actions on Google

Tags: javascript, get, actions-on-google

I am building an actions on google app and I need to identify the users(aka get their email).
I implemented account linking in the following way: since you have to own the endpoint I am hosting a simple webpage that has a "sign in with google button", once the user logs in with his google account an access token gets generated(from google's side, not me), at that point I redirect the user and actions on google gets the authentication token.
So I implemented account linking and it works, now I can get an access token, what's the next step?
I suppose I have to send a GET request to some google api and get the email back, problem is I am having loads of issues with GET requests in javascript (hint: first time javascript here).
Can someone help me out?

Answer (score 0):

You have two potential issues here - one technical one logical.

**Technical Issue - are you running on Firebase?**

If you're using Firebase Functions (which is what Google encourages, *but does not require*) the default "Spark Plan" does not allow outbound function calls except to Google services. So if you're looking to make a GET API call, you will need to update to the "Blaze Plan" (which is listed as a paid plan, but it does have a free level of usage which is good for development and simple deployments.

**Logical Issue - What Account did you link?**

You said you implemented account linking and you get a token - great!

That token represents that You are giving Google permission to access your service on behalf of one of your users. Your user has given you permission to let Google do this. You can use the token to determine which of *your users* has given that permission.

So if you have your user's email address - you can use the token as an index into your database or as a JWT that contains their email address or other claims... but you have to put that email address there in the first place. You can't use it to get the email address that Google has for that user directly.

You *can* have the user, when creating their account with you, authorize your service to ask *Google's identity service* for their email address - but that is a separate process from your service authorizing Google Assistant to talk to you.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but maybe I didn't explain my situation well enough, the account linking I set up does not link a user to an account of my service, as I don't have a service!
All I needed was the get the user's email, and the only way of doing it was apparently to setup account linking, but my account linking page is just a "sign in with google page".
I am running functions on firebase but it shouldn't be an issue since I should be doing the GET request towards one of google's apis I guess.

Comment: Then please update your question to clarify how you have implemented Account Linking. Typically Google does not allow you to use their server as the account linking endpoint.

Comment: Just edited the post, maybe it's more clear this way

Answer (score 0):

The GET request you're looking for, this is done in Node.js

```
    let accestoken = assistant.getUser().accessToken;
    const https = require('https');
    https.get('https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/me?access_token=' + accestoken, (resp) => {

        let jsondata = '';
        // A chunk of data has been recieved.   
        resp.on('data', (chunk) => {
            jsondata += chunk;
        });

        // The whole response has been received. Print out the result.
        resp.on('end', () => {
            parsedData = JSON.parse(jsondata);
            console.log(parsedData);
            //parsedData.emails[0] is the email address
        });
    })
```